# Urlencode forward slash 404 error

Tags: php

```
http://localhost/foo/profile/%26lt%3Bi%26gt%3Bmarco%26lt%3B%2Fi%26gt%3B
```

The url above gives me a `404 Error`, the url code is this: `urlencode(htmlspecialchars($foo));`, as for the `$foo`: `<i>badhtml</i>`

The url works fine when there's nothing to encode e.g. `marco`.

Thanks. =D

Update: I'm supposed to capture the segment in the encoded part of the uri, so a 404 isn't supposed to appear.

There isn't any document there, `marco` is simply the string that I needed to fetch that person's info from db. If the user doesn't exist, it won't throw that ugly error anyways.

**Slight idea what's wrong:** I found out that if I used `<i>badhtml<i>`, it works just fine but `<i>badhtml</i>` won't, what do I do so that I can maintain the `/` in the `<i>`?

It probably think of the request as `http://localhost/foo/profile/<i>badhtml<**/**i>`

Comment: the basic meaning of 404 error is file not found, please check the link whether that path is available or not which u r trying to access.

Comment: Is there a document at that location? Do you have a rewrite that is sending that request to PHP? We will need more information to help you.

Comment: @Guy his point seems to be that if he uses a "normal" value after `profile/`, his URL rewriting works

Comment: Why are you trying to place HTML in the URL in the first place? How are you "capturing" the segment in question? You need to provide more details.

Comment: @Pekka he didn't mention rewriting

Comment: Even if there isn't any document there, it wasn't supposed to throw an error as it will only throw my designed page. I used to to fetch info from db. So for example, user xyz doesn't exist, but it won't throw an ugly error like that.

Comment: Show your rewrite rule then. It might also be `mod_security` kicking in, no idea whether it does stuff like this

Comment: I didn't use any rewriting, I captured the uri segment using codeigniter's php framework function, but that doesn't seem to be the issue as normal values work just fine.

Comment: You probably *are* using rewriting, CI is just doing it for you

Comment: I think I know what's wrong, check the update again.

Comment: </i> the / in <i> causes it to think that it's a new seperate uri segment. What do I do so that I can maintain that?

Comment: OK, well, then change the / into something that can't get interpreted as a separator, and change it back when reading the parameter.

Comment: Okay, that's pretty smart lol. Thanks.

Comment: @MrLister Hey, write it as an answer, I'll accept it. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a slash `/` in the parameter, this is getting interpreted as a path name separator.

The solution, therefore, is to replace all occurrences of a slash with something that doesn't get interpreted as a separator. `\u2044` or something. And when reading the parameter back in, change all `\u2044`s back to normal slashes.

(I chose `\u2044` because this character looks remarkably like a normal slash, but you can use anthing that would never occur in the parameter, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that the regex responsible for handling the URL rewrite does not like some of the characters in the URL-encoded string. This is most likely httpd/apache question, rather than PHP. Your best guess is to start by looking at the `.htaccess` (file containing URL rewrite rules).

This question assumes that your are trying to pass an argument through the URL, rather than access a file named `<i>badhtml</i>`.

Answer (score -1):

Mr. Lister, you rocked.

"The solution, therefore, is to replace all occurrences of a slash with something that doesn't get interpreted as a separator. \u2044 or something. And when reading the parameter back in, change all \u2044s back to normal slashes."